# Compiling time and indexing

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uisearchbar

I have used `Build Time Analyzer` to check how long my app is taking to compile and it turns out that the following function takes 60000 ms to compile if it's in an extension of the `viewController`, and 30000ms if it is inside the `viewController`

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

                if numberSearch.text == nil || numberSearch.text == "" {

                    inSearchMode = false
                    filteredData.removeAll()

                    analyticsTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index:0) as IndexSet, with: .fade)
                    view.endEditing(true)

                } else {

                    inSearchMode = true


                    let lowerCase = numberSearch.text!

                        switch lowerCase {

                        case _ where lowerCase.contains("."):

                            // AMOUNT

                            for (index, value) in inputData.enumerated() {

                                switch value.total! {

                                case (Float(lowerCase)! - Float(1))...(Float(lowerCase)! + Float(1)):

                                    filteredData.append(inputData[index])

                                default:
                                    print("default")
                                }

                            analyticsTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index:0) as IndexSet, with: .fade)

                            }

                        case _ where lowerCase.contains("/"):

                            // DATE

                            for (index, value) in inputData.enumerated() {

                                if value.dateIn.contains(lowerCase) {

                                    filteredData.append(inputData[index])

                                }

                            }

                            analyticsTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index:0) as IndexSet, with: .fade)

                        case _ where lowerCase.contains(":"):

                            // TIME

                            for (index, value) in inputData.enumerated() {

                                if value.timeIn == lowerCase {

                                    filteredData.append(inputData[index])

                                }

                            }

                            analyticsTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index:0) as IndexSet, with: .fade)

                        default:

                            for (index, value) in inputData.enumerated() {

                                if value.number == Int(lowerCase) {

                                    filteredData.append(inputData[index])

                                }

                            }

                            analyticsTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index:0) as IndexSet, with: .fade)
                        }        
                }

            }
```

I would like to understand why it's taking so much time, as I have substituted if statements with a switch statement and it seems to make it worse for some reason.

Is there any other alternative for this?

The reason I have included a (.), (/) and (:), is to filter results based on Amount, Date and Time. Is there any other approach to get the same results? I am using a searchbar because it filters the results immediately